# PHP and AJAX login Script secure enough?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I want to create a dynamic login on my website using ajax (with jquery).
Now everything is done, and everything works well.
My problem is, that i dont know, if everything works secure (enough) to use it, like it's now.

My ajax script:

```
//LOGIN
$(function(){
  var mail;
  var password;
  $("body").on("click", ".sign-in", function(event){
    mail = $('#login-mail').val();
    password = $('#login-password').val();
    //ajax
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      url: '/index.php',
      data:  { 'mail': mail,'password': password},
      success: function (msg)
        {

          if($(msg).filter('.logged-in').html() == 'success'){
            window.location.replace('/timeline.php')
          }else{
            $('input').css('border','0.1rem solid #EB5757');
            $('.login-failed').html('Falsche E-Mail oder / und Passwort !');
          }
        },
      error: function (err)
      { alert(err.responseText)}
    });
  });
});
```

The logic behind this:
Ajax sends the user and pass to a PhP page:

```
if(isset($_POST["mail"]) && isset($_POST["password"])){
  //$mU->hashPassword($_POST['password']);
  if($mU->loginUser($_POST["mail"],$_POST["password"]) == true)
  echo '<div class="logged-in">success</div>';
}
```

`$mU->loginUser($_POST["mail"],$_POST["password"]) == true` when true, everything is fine. Then the Script "echos" success.
In my ajax success function, jquery checks the content of the div.

I hope you know what i mean, because its very hard to explain my "problem".
Is my Script secure ? What can I do better (security) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code belong on Code Review SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is secure, you are using your php just as an api. you can pass a key from javascript to make it more secure and for csrf protection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I would replace the login url last segment (e.g. /login.php) with /timeline.php and this would show me your 'login protected' timeline your script would not be secure. Typically some session variable (set during a successful authentication) determines whether a page is accessible or not.